# How to sort a Diary?

Tags: sort

Diary has entries with month and day, no years, in the format `%D_%M.tex` but index in wrong order because of wrong sorting and poor filename -format. How should I call my Diary -entries to get them sortable by sort -command (from old to new or the reverse)? The key is radix -sorting, notice this discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4320097#4320097), but it is still open which one of them. By which Radix -sorting algorithms and when? What are the pros-and-cons?

**STOP here if you know sorting -- the following part is for those wanting to reproduce the diary with small working example and intended output**

> **Wrong Output**
>
> ```
>  $ ls Days/ |sort -M 
>  12_4.tex 
>  29_3.tex 
>  3_4.tex
> ```
>
> **Intended Output**
>
> ```
>  29_3.tex 
>  3_4.tex 
>  12_4.tex
> ```
>
> **Small example (with wrong sorting -order n.b. the radix -bug)**
>
> ```
> $ ls Days/
> 12_4.tex  29_3.tex  3_4.tex
> $ cat Makefile 
> .PHONY: all
> all:   days.tex  
>
> days.tex: $(wildcard Days/*.tex)
>   ls Days/*.tex | awk '{printf "\\input{%s}\n", $$1}' > days.tex
> $ make; pdflatex diary.tex
> $ cat diary.tex
> \documentclass{article}         
> \begin{document}     
> \input{days}
> \end{document}
> ```

**Related**

1. Radix sorts in Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: When do you write entries.  If you write them fresh on the day, the the solution could be as simple as `ls -1t`

Comment: @emory: good observation but I fool in this diary because it is a course-must-do -diary for the course [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/kie-98.6062/etusivu). So I need to re-edit and improve it later but good start! Nice one-liner!

Comment: Extremely good discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4320097#4320097), simplicity rocks! `%Y_%M_%D` makes it like a radix number, easy to sort. I think this question although got excellent answers in chat belongs here because it is a practical example how to use sorting in practise, cool.

Comment: Wikipedia: `"Unlike a least significant digit (LSD) radix sort, a most significant digit radix sort does not necessarily preserve the original order of duplicate keys."` -- and something about radix-sorting in tri-structure, the structure can change the result of the same algorithm. The LSD reserving the original order can become handy...investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to rename the files:

```
for FILE in Days/*
do
      DAY=`cut --delimiter '_' --fields 1 ${FILE}`
      MONTH=`cut --delimiter '_' --fields 2 ${FILE} | cut --delimiter '.' --fields 1
      NEWFILE=${MONTH}_${DAY}.tex
      cp ${FILE} ${NEWFILE}
done
```

or you could use the `touch` command so that `ls -1t` would work.

Comment: +1 for implicitly using the Radix -format, yes it is the key -- now the puzzle is when and which radix sorting to use with a diary. Pros and cons?